# How can I show the command line YouCompleteMe is using to compile my file?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

I believe I am experiencing some weirdness in how YouCompleteMe is compiling my files to do its syntax checking. I suspect settings from my `.ycm_extra_conf.py` are not being applied the way I think they are, or YouCompleteMe is using a compiler I'm not expecting, or something along those lines. If I could just see the command line YouCompleteMe is using when it compiles the file, I think there's a good chance I could diagnose my problem.

Does anyone know how to show the command line YouCompleteMe is using?

Comment: ask at YouCompleteMe issue tracker?

Comment: Yes, I may need to do that. I find the StackExchange format much more effective than digging through issue trackers, though, so I thought I'd ask here for the future benefit of anyone else who has the same problem. If nobody here knows, I'll try to find an answer there and report back here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digging through the [`ycm-users` Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/ycm-users), I found a post by someone else who was trying to debug their `.ycm_extra_conf.py` flag settings and was using `:YcmDebugInfo` to get information about the flags being used by YouCompleteMe to compile their file.

As documented [here](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#commands), `:YcmDebugInfo` "...will print out various debug information for the current file. Useful to see what compile commands will be used for the file if you're using the semantic completion engine". So... clearly I did not RTFM.

`:YcmDebugInfo` was enough for me to diagnose my problem and debug some changes I'd made to my `.ycm_extra_conf.py`.

Comment: If anyone else has a better answer -- mine does not actually show the command line YouCompleteMe is using, as I'd originally asked -- I'll happily choose their answer over my own.

Comment: I'm using YCM with clangd. Invoking :YcmDebugInfo when in the buffer for the source file gives me the paths of the 'Clangd logfiles' (just one actually). These files hold the commands that clangd runs for compiling the source file.